# Symfony 5 global dynamic configuration file

Tags: php, deployment, config, symfony5

I'm a long time Zend Framework user (now renamed Laminas). But I decided to give a try to last Symfony version. So I just installed it in 5.1.2.

I'm facing a question regarding the multiple environments deployments. In my compay, we have :

- Local environment which is developer pc.
- Development.
- Staging.
- Production.

In ZF-Laminas, we have a global.php file which is located in config directory.
For those of you who are not familiar with this framework, you can override key set in global.php file by creating local.php file.

In this global file, I use to put standard configuration for my application.

For example (prod) :

```
'open_id' => [
   'client_id' => 1234
]
```

Then, I have development and staging files which car override those values for every environmenet. During the deployment, the file corresponding to the environment is copied to local.php.

Let's say staging.local.php.dist becomes local.php with :

```
'open_id' => [
   'client_id' => 5678
]
```

Which is fine because value is overriding the one from global file.

I would like the same behavior in Symfony but I don't see something similar in Symfony 5.

So far, I only found two possibilities

- Create a bundle which will allow me to have a <bundle_name>.yaml file in config/packages directory. According to the documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-files), I will be able to have dev, prod and staging overrides. But it forces me to create a bundle to handle just some standard configurations, which is huge.
- Use .env files. But .env files only allow string data, not complex data like arrays.

What do I miss ? Or is it my "zend" way of doing things that is wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create services_%env%.yaml (`services_dev.yaml`, `services_test.yaml`) files for each environment. It will allow you to define different parameters and override/define services for each environment.

Example:
`config/services_dev.yaml`

```
parameters:
    hello: 'world'
```

Comment: It seems it's no longer a possibility in Syfmony 5 but thanks.

Comment: Nope it should work, I use It in my Symfony5 projects.
Try `bin/console about` to see if your `kernel.environment` is correct

Comment: Ok, you are right. I like this solution ! After cache:clear, it saw my services_dev.yaml file. But I still can not find it in the documentation which is kinda strange.

Comment: Cannot find it too. It is very strange, because this feature have been implemented in  very early framework versions.

Found one mention here https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#accessing-the-container and that's all...

Comment: This method of loading service files is done in the Kernel.php. You can see this in the demo project on github: https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/master/src/Kernel.php

Comment: Here you can find the documentation for it. It's still possible in Symfony 5.
https://symfony.com/doc/5.0/best_practices.html#use-parameters-for-application-configuration

Comment: I feel you. I am coming from Laminas to Symfony 6 and wondering about something different but related. I want to be able to name a log file dynamically based on the current date. That was so easy in Laminas I think iirc I got the idea from an example in the docs. In Symfony it appears that the more general question is how to you put dynamic (not environment-dependent) values in a config. Let me know if you find out :-)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your post, your goal is to have different config values based on the server you are on. If this is the case, you can use environment variables (in the .env file or .env.local for server specific config). You can then use these values in your applications by binding the env var to a parameter. This parameter will then be available within the configuration by using `%parameter_name%` as value or within the container. You can also pas parameters to services (service definitions are handled the same way as any other config). For more information you can checkout these sources:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/env_var_processors.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, this is something I saw but I'm surprised there is no dynamic config file. As far as I remember that was possible in SF3.

Comment: Could you be more specific with what you mean by "dynamic configuration"?

Comment: Dynamic configuration based on environment (dev/staging/prod).

Comment: Sorry for my late reaction. For that you can load config files based on the configuration in the Kernel. This is already done with the default installation and you should be able to add a config_dev.yaml that will only be loaded in your development environment. Same goes for test and prod. If you want to create another environment (like staging), you can just add a config file for that environment like config_staging.yml and than it should work.